# How to get total numbers of nested divs under multiple individual divs?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

Here how can i get the total numbers of divs of class = "row ehi-pd", under each divs of class = "panel-content"?
As shown in the picture.

it should give the output for each class = "panel-content" section separately, not combining all of them.

for example:

for 1st "panel-content" : 6

for 2nd "panel-content" : 5

for 3rd "panel-content" : 3

[image: picture]

Comment: please include html using the snippet tool via [edit] and also your attempt at coding and where stuck. Guidance on posting is given in [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good with @kajal solution but just want to add other option using css.

**Using CSS:**

```
panels = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.panel-content')
for panelNum in range(len(panels)):
    #get the divs count
    panelDivs = len(panels[panelNum].find_elements_by_css_selector("div.row.ehi-pd"))
    print str(panelNum+1) + " panel-content:" + str(panelDivs)
```

Comment: sir, actually i want the output for each class = "panel-content" section not combining all of them.

for example:

for 1st "panel-content" : 6,

for 2nd "panel-content" : 5,

for 3rd "panel-content" : 3

Answer (score 0):

use `find_elements_by_xpath` and take the length count.

```
totalcount= len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel-content']/div[@class='row ehi-pd']"))
print(totalcount)
```

Comment: sir, actually i want the output for each class = "panel-content" section not combining all of them.

for example:

for 1st "panel-content" : 6,

for 2nd "panel-content" : 5,

for 3rd "panel-content" : 3

Answer (score 0):

To print the total numbers of nested `<div>` tags with *class attribute* as  **row ehi-pd** within the ancestor `<div>` tag  with *class attribute* as  **panel-content** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.panel-content div.row.ehi-pd")))
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel-content']//div[@class='row ehi-pd']")))
  ```

Comment: sir, actually i want the output for each class = "panel-content" section not combining all of them.

for example:

for 1st "panel-content" : 6,

for 2nd "panel-content" : 5,

for 3rd "panel-content" : 3

Comment: In that case you have to update the question with text based HTML including a bit more of the outer HTML.